# Firestore error when adding a value to a collection with API 16 and 17

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add/get a value to a collection in firebase. It is working fine with a mobile with Android 6.0.0 and another with Android 8.1.0 but when I am trying to do de same with an Android 4.2.0 it fails with this exception message:

`com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.`

Here is the peace of code that I am using:

```
private val userCollections = firestore.collection(USERS)

private fun getCollectionDocument(collectionId: String, id: String) = Single.create<FavoriteData> { single ->
    userCollections.document(FirebaseObject.userId).collection(collectionId)
            .document(id)
            .get()
            .addOnCanceledListener {
                if (!single.isDisposed) {
                    single.onError(FirebaseCancelled())
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                if (!single.isDisposed) {
                    single.onError(it)
                }
            }
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if (!single.isDisposed) {
                    single.onSuccess(favoriteDataMapper.map(it))
                }
            }
}
```

With Api 16 mobile it goes to addOnFailureListener with the message I wrote above.

Comment: Android 4.0 (API level 14) is the minimum for Firebase to work. So in Android 4.2.0, you shouldn't have a problem. Perhaps you should [file a bug report](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) to the Firebase team.

Comment: Are you using an emulator? It could actually be because your device was not connecting.

Comment: In both, emulator and real device, is giving me the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your project into androidx  . You can find the option migrate to androidx under navigate option . May be this will help because androidx will give you backward comparability .

Comment: I am using androidx in my project so this is not the issue.